# Pass value and use as object properties dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way I can pass a parameter value into a function and use it as properties of an object?

```
const state = {
  name: 'xyz',
  properties: 'abc'
}
...
const handleStuff = (properties:string) => {
        const a = [...state.properties]
        if (action.status == true)
        {
            //some code
            return {
                ...state,
                properties: a
            }
        } else {
            //some code
            return {
                ...state,
                properties: a
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the typeof  `properties`, is it an array?

Comment: I think you are looking for computed names: `{ [properties]: a }`, but then `properties` must be (or convert to) a string, and it will be *one* property despite its name. Better provide an example input and expected result.

Comment: I want the 'properties' to be string, then some how I can process that value to the same as state properties. For example, If the parameter is 'name', I want to be able to access state properties by using 'state.name' .I have edited the code, hope it will clear up what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not clear what result you are trying to reach, but generally you can access your properties by [] operator.
if you want just to store state.name value into variable you should do following

```
const a = state[properties] // a will be 'xyz'
```

code below will be evaluated as spread operation performed on the string 'xyz'

```
const a = [...state[properties]] // a will be equal to ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

in your return statement, where you want to combine object and if you want to assign value to property with name properties (which is 'name' for example) you can

```
return {
  ...state,
  [properties]: a // name value from the state will be overridden with value of variable a
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.